# Attach two listeners to single axios stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I am trying to fetch pdf url as stream from axios. I need to further upload that file to another location and return the hash of the uploaded file. I have third party function which accepts the stream, and upload file to target location. How can I use same stream to get the hash of the file?
I am trying to run below code:

```
const getFileStream = await axios.get<ReadStream>(externalUrl, {
    responseType: "stream"
});
const hashStream = crypto.createHash("md5");
hashStream.setEncoding("hex");
const pHash = new Promise<string>(resolve => {
    getFileStream.data.on("finish", () => {
      resolve(hashStream.read());
 });
});

const pUploadedFile = externalUploader({
  stream: () => getFileStream.data
});

getFileStream.data.pipe(hashStream);

const [hash, uploadedFile] = await Promise.all([pHash, pUploadedFile]);

return { hash, id: uploadedFile.id };
```

After running this code, when I download the same pdf, I am getting corrupted file

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the same axios `getFileStream.data` to pipe to multiple sinks as long as they are consumed simultaneously.

Below is an example of downloading a file using an axios stream and "concurrently" calculating the MD5 checksum of the file while uploading it to a remote server.

The example will output stdout:

```
Incoming file checksum: 82c12f208ea18bbeed2d25170f3669a5
File uploaded. Awaiting server response...
File uploaded. Done.
```

Working example:

```js
const { Writable, Readable, Transform, pipeline } = require('stream');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios');

(async ()=>{
  // Create an axios stream to fetch the file
  const axiosStream = await axios.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Map_icon.svg/128px-Map_icon.svg.png', {
      responseType: "stream"
  }); 

  // To re-upload the file to a remote server, we can use multipart/form-data which will require a boundary key
  const key = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

  // Create a request to stream the file as multipart/form-data to another server
  const req = https.request({
    hostname: 'postman-echo.com',
    path: '/post',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=--${key}`,
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
    }
  });

  // Create a promise that will be resolved/rejected when the remote server has completed the HTTP(S) request
  const uploadRequestPromise = new Promise(resolve => req.once('response', (incomingMessage) => {
    incomingMessage.resume(); // prevent response data from queuing up in memory
    incomingMessage.on('end', () => {
      if(incomingMessage.statusCode === 200){
        resolve();
      }
      else {
        reject(new Error(`Received status code ${incomingMessage.statusCode}`))
      }
    });
  }));

  // Construct the multipart/form-data delimiters
  const multipartPrefix = `\r\n----${key}\r\n` +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="cool-name.png"\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: image/png\r\n' +
      '\r\n';
  const multipartSuffix = `\r\n----${key}--`;

  // Write the beginning of a multipart/form-data request before streaming the file content
  req.write(multipartPrefix);

  // Create a promise that will be fulfilled when the file has finished uploading
  const uploadStreamFinishedPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    pipeline(
      // Use the axios request as a stream source
      axiosStream.data,
      // Piggyback a nodejs Transform stream because of the convenient flush() call that can
      // add the multipart/form-data suffix
      new Transform({
        objectMode: false,
        transform( chunk, encoding, next ){
          next( null, chunk );
        },
        flush( next ){
          this.push( multipartSuffix );
          next();
        }
      }),
      // Write the streamed data to a remote server
      req,
      // This callback is executed when all data from the stream pipe has been processed
      (error) => {
        if( error ){
          reject( error );
        }
        else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
    )
  });

  // Create a MD5 stream hasher
  const hasher = crypto.createHash("md5");

  // Create a promise that will be resolved when the hash function has processed all the stream
  // data
  const hashPromise = new Promise(resolve => pipeline(
      // Use the axios request as a stream source.
      // Note that it's OK to use the same stream to pipe into multiple sinks. In this case, we're
      // using the same axios stream for both calculating the haas, and uploading the file above
      axiosStream.data,
      // The has function will process stream data 
      hasher,
      // This callback is executed when all data from the stream pipe has been processed
      (error) => {
        if( error ){
          reject( error );
        }
        else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
    ));

  /**
   * Note that there are no 'awaits' before both stream sinks have been established. That is 
   * important since we want both sinks to process data from the beginning of stream
   */

  // We must wait to call the hash function's digest() until all the data has been processed
  await hashPromise;
  const hash = hasher.digest("hex");
  console.log("Incoming file checksum:", hash);

  await uploadStreamFinishedPromise;
  console.log("File uploaded. Awaiting server response...");
  await uploadRequestPromise;
  console.log("File uploaded. Done.");
})()
  .catch( console.error );
```